Converting latitude and longitude to coordinates within an image
I'm creating a game which involves fetching data from an API which gives me the latitude and longitude of some entities. I have a picture of size 1280x720 (zoom 100km / 50 mi) (I converted the image from 1207x811 to 1280x720) that contains the following longitudes and latitudes:

North = 59.512  East = 9.888  South = 49.239  West = -16.633

How do I convert those entities longitudes and latitudes to coordinates within my image?
I have tried with the following code:
  const float north = imgBounds[0];
  const float south = imgBounds[2];
  const float east = imgBounds[1];
  const float west = imgBounds[3];

  const float width = gameResolution.first;
  const float height = gameResolution.second;

  float x = floor(((crtLongitude - south) / (north - south)) * width);
  float y = floor(((east - crtLatitude) / (east - west)) * height);

  // crtLongitude -> entity longitude
  // crtLatitude -> entity latitude

And the results are not quite what I was expecting:
An entity which is on the north-west of UK (second image) appears in the eastern part of UK
(first image)



In what projection is you image?

I think it is Web Mercator projection

Then have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103924/mercator-longitude-and-latitude-calculations-to-x-and-y-on-a-cropped-map-of-the/10401734#10401734

Also take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames. It contains an example for how to convert a GPS coordinate to a pixel position in a Web Mercator tile.
